# iOS 7 UIWebView doesn't load webpage

Tags: uiwebview, ios7

My app uses UIWebview, and it works well in iOS 5 and iOS 6. However, it doesn't load the webpage in iOS 7 when I build in Xcode 5 and run the same code.

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
 - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {}
```

All delegate function is not called. But I do set delegate in xib file and code

```
self.theWebView.delegate = self;
```

I didn't find any information via google. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you verified that theWebView is being loaded? Is it visible on the screen and in the debugger?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean theWebView is being loaded. All the delegate functions are not called in iOS7, I trace it, theWebView is not nil. I set break point in webViewDidStartLoad, and webViewDidStartLoad is not called, so it seems uiwebview doesn't load the web page....

Comment: OK theWebView is not nil, that's what I was asking.

Comment: Do you subclass `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I moved the loadRequest method to the completion handler of a presentViewController and it works in iOS 5, 6 and 7:

```
[self presentViewController:gwvc animated:YES completion:^(void){
    [gwvc.wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.walkjogrun.net/about/eukanuba.html"]]];
}];
```

Comment: Similarly, I needed to move the call to loadRequest: into viewDidAppear.

Comment: This didn't help me, but the cause was that my web view in IB got autosynthesized to _webV instead of webV. Just check if the webview in your loadrequest is not nil.

Answer (score 4):

I found the root cause.
 maybe I incorrectly used `UIWebView`, but it works in iOS5 and iOS6.
 I don't know why it works in earlier iOS versions...

Moreover, it works in iOS7 when I build code with SDK 6.1.

Here's my old code.

```
     RechargeWebPageViewController *webPageViewController;
    webPageViewController = [[  RechargeWebPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebPage" bundle:nil];
    if (webPageViewController != nil) {
        webPageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        webPageViewController.delegate=self;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webPageViewController animated:YES];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx.php"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
        [webPageViewController loadRequest:request];
        [request release];
   }
```

I moved the `loadRequest` from the `viewDidLoad` method to the `ViewWillAppear` method, then it worked.
   I think maybe `UIWebView` is not initialized correctly in my old code for iOS7.

Comment: I still call loadRequest in viewDidLoad and it doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: The problem of my code is I call pushViewcontroller first, then I call loadRequest.  It seems we need to call loadRequest in ViewwillAppear or ViewdidLoad.  In this way, we can make sure the UIWebview is initilized and ready to receive events of loadRequest. This is just my guess.

Comment: If pushing the web view controller onto a navigation controller with animation, then I found that loadRequest needs to be done in viewDidAppear.